# Using Entity Model with AngularJS to populate radio options from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to populate radio options using Entity Framework and Angular.  I have created what I want in this fiddle: [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/shaximinion/jx7f5r4x/3/)

How can I do this using Entity Framework? I have got the data back from the Controller fine... Its just binding the results to the radio buttons...

Columns in EntityFrameworkJSScopeName are Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4 & Option5 along with the record identifier which is ANIMAL_NAME.

Here is the code:

```
    <div ng-controller="DropdownPopulation" class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="AnimalGrp">Copy detail from:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="formData.animalSelected" required id="AnimalGrp" data-ng-options="c.ANIMAL_NAME as c.ANIMAL_NAME for c in EntityFrameworkJSScopeName">
        <option value="" selected>Select Animal</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="r in EntityFrameworkJSScopeName | filter: formData.animalSelected">
{{r.Option1}}  <!-- This displays the value fine on page, either RED, AMBER or GREEN -->
<div class="form-group">

    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Option 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option1" data-ng-model="{{r.Option1}}" value="Red">Red</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option1" data-ng-model="{{r.Option1}}" value="Amber">Amber</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option1" data-ng-model="{{r.Option1}}" value="Green">Green</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Option 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option2" data-ng-model="{{r.Option2}}" value="Red">Red</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option2" data-ng-model="{{r.Option2}}" value="Amber">Amber</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option2" data-ng-model="{{r.Option2}}" value="Green">Green</label>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Option 3</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option3" data-ng-model="{{r.Option3}}" value="Red">Red</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option3" data-ng-model="{{r.Option3}}" value="Amber">Amber</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option3" data-ng-model="{{r.Option3}}" value="Green">Green</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Option 4</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option4" data-ng-model="{{r.Option4}}" value="Red">Red</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option4" data-ng-model="{{r.Option4}}" value="Amber">Amber</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option4" data-ng-model="{{r.Option4}}" value="Green">Green</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Option 5</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option5" data-ng-model="{{r.Option5}}" value="Red">Red</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option5" data-ng-model="{{r.Option5}}" value="Amber">Amber</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="Option5" data-ng-model="{{r.Option5}}" value="Green">Green</label>
    </div>
</div>  

</div>
```

Comment: Normally, [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tag is pretty active, and you'll get answer within few minutes. It seems that you question is too long and confusing - how EF relates to angular html view. Please narrow down the question and remove redundant codes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i managed to get this sorted by setting the value of the $scope in my js.file by using:

```
        $scope.GetRemainingRAGS = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Data/GetRemainingRAGS',
            data: JSON.stringify({ ANIMAL_NAME: $scope.formData.animalSelected})
        }).
             success(function (data) {
                 $scope.theColours = data;

                 //associating column values to scope on html
                 $scope.Option1 = $scope.theColours[0].Option1;
                 $scope.Option2 = $scope.theColours[0].Option2;
                 $scope.Option3 = $scope.theColours[0].Option3;
                 $scope.Option4 = $scope.theColours[0].Option4;
                 $scope.Option5 = $scope.theColours[0].Option5;
             })
    };
```

And then my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-2">Option 1</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="Option1" ng-model="Option1" value="RED">Red</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="Option1" ng-model="Option1" value="AMBER">Amber</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="Option1" ng-model="Option1" value="GREEN">Green</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

.. and repeated for the 5 Options